# Capture different intent actions for different notification buttons

Tags: android

I am attempting to capture an `Intent` action from one of two action buttons on a notification. I know I could leverage BroadcastReceivers, but I need to handle both actions in the same `Activity`.

I'll provide my code, but here's what I'm doing (incorrectly) in a nutshell...

1. I have one result `Intent` called `mResultIntent`.
2. I invoke `.setAction` on it.
3. I create another `Intent` object, called `buttonTwoIntent`, and set its value to the primary result Intent, `mResultIntent`. My reason for doing this is because I need the `extras` data...for both buttons.
4. `.setAction` is invoked on both `Intent` objects, and this is the difference between the two `Intent` objects.
5. I create two `PendingIntent` objects and pass them into separate `.addAction` invocations (to add the buttons).
6. Finally, I invoke .setContentIntent, passing one of the `PendingIntent` objects.

Here's my relevant code (other code removed since that's working fine):

```
...
mResultIntent.setAction("button_one_action");
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mResultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), mChannelId);
mNotificationBuilder.setContentTitle("title");
mNotificationBuilder.setContentText("body text");
mNotificationBuilder.setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE);
mNotificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ico_default);
mNotificationBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
mNotificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

if (mNotification.getActionId().equalsIgnoreCase(PushNotificationManager.NOTIFICATION_TYPE)) {

    // BUTTON TWO ACTION
    Intent buttonTwoIntent = mResultIntent;
    buttonTwoIntent.setAction("button_two_action");
    PendingIntent buttonTwoPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, buttonTwoIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); mNotificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_check_in, "button 2", buttonTwoPendingIntent);

    // BUTTON ONE ACTION
    mNotificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_check_in, "button 1", resultPendingIntent);
}
mNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
...
```

The problem is that only BUTTON ONE opens the Activity, BUTTON TWO does not. I expect is has something to do with using `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, but I don't see any issues with how I'm doing that. Nothing should be overwritten, but I'm likely missing something. Please help, and thank you!

Comment: The names in your question do not match your code. For example, `resultIntentSecondary` is in the question but not the code. Note that `Intent buttonTwoIntent = mResultIntent;` is just creating another reference to the same `Intent` object, so your `buttonTwoIntent.setAction()` call is modifying the same object that `mResultIntent` points to. If you want to make a copy, use `Intent buttonTwoIntent = new Intent(mResultIntent)`, to invoke the copy constructor.

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare. I wrote my questions in haste. I made the edits, but I think your suggestion to use buttonTwoIntent = new Intent(mResultIntent) is the key. Based on my edits, would you suggest anything different?

Comment: I would start there. Also, how are you creating `mResultIntent` in the first place? Are you using the constructor that takes a Java `Class` as a parameter?

Comment: I'm not. It's created with the parameterless constructor: `Intent mResultIntent = new Intent()`. Then, based on some conditions (i.e. push notification payload data), I call .setData and pass in a Uri object that deep links to the class. Note, this is an existing implementation. Being new to Android, I'm certainly open to any suggestions you'd have on this. Thanks, again, @CommonsWare.

Comment: Unfortunately, using the Intent copy constructor didn't do the trick. From my code above, I replaced `Intent buttonTwoIntent = mResultIntent;` with `Intent buttonTwoIntent = new Intent(mResultIntent);`.

Comment: "I call .setData and pass in a Uri object that deep links to the class" -- it might be tied to something in there. I do not work with deep linking much. You might try commenting out creating the first-action `PendingIntent` and corresponding action logic. If Button 2 now works, you know that it is a problem with creating the two `PendingIntent` objects. If Button 2 still does not work, then my guess is that it is tied to the `Intent`. Logcat may have some debug messages from the system that are logged when you click Button 2 that may give you some clues.